# Merging PDF Files in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdfkit

I would like to concatenate several PDF files to form one single PDF.
Now I've come so far that I know, PDFKit is the proper way to go (I guess).
But I am not sure, how to accomplish the merging. 
Should I have one `PDFDocument` and several `PDFPage` and then call `insertPage` on the `PDFDocument` ?
Or is there a much simpler way? I dont want to alter the PDFs contetwise, I just want to merge them.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you indicated, you need one output `PDFDocument` object which will contain all pages of all input PDF files. To do so, you'll need to loop through all input files, create `PDFDocument` objects for each one and iterate over all pages to add them using `insertPage` to the output `PDFDocument` object.

Assuming that `inputDocuments` is an `NSArray` of one ore more `PDFDocument` objects, you can use this snippet:

```
PDFDocument *outputDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] init];
NSUInteger pageIndex = 0;
for (PDFDocument *inputDocument in inputDocuments) {
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [inputDocument pageCount]; j++) {
        PDFPage *page = [inputDocument pageAtIndex:j];
        [outputDocument insertPage:page atIndex:pageIndex++];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not quite sure how this would work, when I try to use "fast enumeration" on a `PDFDocument` I get, `Collection expression type "PDFDocument *" may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'`

Comment: Yes, you have to iterate through all the pages of each PDFDocument. I fixed the error.