# Can we display many pdf in a UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can we display many pdf/doc in only one webview?

For example, I have 3 pdf files to be loaded in single UIWebview:

> PDF 1 (as the first)
>
> PDF 2 (as the second)
>
> PDF 3 (as the third)

I didn't find any reference for it.

Comment: You display as many PDFs as you want.

Comment: Is it? How about the code? AFAIK webview load the pdf by [webview loadRequest:urlRequest]; which only has one url (pdf)..

Comment: What do you mean? At once ?!?

Comment: Yes, I want to display some pdf in one uiwebview.. Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you mean multiple pages, or multiple files?

Comment: One right after another or what? You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question again

Comment: @Rendy: Why one webview? Why not creating multiple webviews?

Comment: Because I want to create my code is simple. I also think multiple webviews are not allowed? Because I think I need a scrollview if I have multiple webviews, so that the webviews are not too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIWebView [displays one file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749). If you need multiple PDF files to be displayed consecutively in a UIWebView, you can:

1. Use Adobe Acrobat to combine them
2. Combine them programmatically by [Merging PDF Files in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610521/merging-pdf-files-in-cocoa)

Comment: I agree with your options.. I will try it later.. Btw, if I want to have an image too below the pdf, can I do that in one webview? Sorry to ask it now, the additional requirement of the app was just given :(

Comment: You could maybe add the image to a page of the PDF.