# Show multiple PDF with one UIwebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.6

I hope someone can help me.
In one view of the app I've got a UIWebView where I'm showing the PDF file. I need to show 3 different PDF (a.pdf, b.pdf, c.pdf) in the same UIWebView. I know how to show one.

```
    CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(20, 25, 280, 350);
    testWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2]; 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"doc"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [apneaWebView loadRequest:request];
    [apneaWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:testWebView];
```

But if are 3 different PDf what to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at that: [Can we display many pdf in a UIWebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847530/can-we-display-many-pdf-in-a-uiwebview)

You can only display a pdf in a UIWebView. You can try to create 3 different UIWebViews for every PDF or try to merge them.

Comment: I dont want put 3 pdf in the same time. Just one at time, i was thinking, maybe i can do an Arrya with my 3 Pdf and after load the one that i need.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah sure, put the name string of every pdf file in an array and then load it into the UIWebView when you need them.

Comment: I know how to the Array but I've got some problem to figure out the code to load the Pdf, can you help with this. I'm quiet new on programming. Thanks in advance