# how to convert a selected image from iphone library to pdf in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext

Now i am using this code. Pdf is generating but image is not displaying.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"%@",info);    
    //selectedImage =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];        
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];        
    NSLog(@" selected image is - %@",image);
    imageStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",image]; 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *localFilePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images.pdf"];
    NSLog(@"file path is %@",localFilePath);
    [self pdfGenerate:localFilePath];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)pdfGenerate:(NSString *)filepath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filepath, CGRectZero, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300), nil);
    [self convertImageToPdf];
}

-(void)convertImageToPdf
{
    CGRect imagerect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    NSLog(@"image  is %@",imageStr);
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageStr];
    [image drawInRect:imagerect];
}
```

Comment: pdf ??? you are saving the image picked from the photolibrary into a UIImage .... thats all ... Where are you doing the "Conversion" ?

Comment: i am doing conversion..but i did't mention that code..

Comment: wud like to see that as thats ur question ....

Comment: ok...i will post my pdf conversion code ..

Comment: hi..i have posted my code exactly what i am using.In that i am generating pdf file but in that image is not showing.Suggest any solution.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the selected image in NSString object `imageStr`  (imageStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",image];)

So when you are creating the image inside `convertImageToPdf` method (UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageStr];), your image object is `nil`. so the pdf is blank.

Instead you can have UIImage reference to the image you picked from the picker. Use that reference inside `convertImageToPdf` to draw.

Update to your code:

Inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
pickedImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Inside `convertImageToPdf`

```
CGRect imagerect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[pickedImage drawInRect:imagerect];
```

`pickedImage` is an object of type UIImage.

Comment: hi @prasdad how can we merge multiple pdf files in one web view by using page numbers?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847530/can-we-display-many-pdf-in-a-uiwebview